# Where would I store a txt file in Laravel 5 so i can read it?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently at my project root I have

```
/checklist_templates
  checklist-test.txt
```

and in one of my controllers I want to read that file in my `index()` method.

```
public function index()
{
  $contents = \File::get('/checklist_templates/checklist-test.txt');
}
```

But for some reason I keep getting the error:

`File does not exist at path /checklist_templates/checklist-test.txt`

Anyone know what might be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: what is  "checklist-test.txt" file path?

Comment: Use the full file path.

Comment: you can store file under public folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own answer. I guess Laravel wants the full route when opening a file so I had to use the following:

```
$contents = \File::get(base_path('/checklist_templates/checklist-test.txt'));
```